# Using weightsum to adjust layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is the screenshot of one of my fragments (device: Xiaomi Redmi 2)
[image]

The fragment is divided into 4 parts:

- A ViewPager to display image ads
- A ViewPager indicator
- A RecyclerView which contains a bunch of CardViews (to display news)
- An [AHBottomNavigation](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation)

And this is its corresponding XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1.5">

        <!-- for displaying ads -->
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llDots"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- for displaying news -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/news_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.5" />

    <!-- bottom navigation -->  
    <com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I think the height of the ViewPager Indicator and the AHBottomView is right. But the ViewPager height is too much. What I want is the height of the ViewPager to fit the height of the image ads, and the height of the RecyclerView is bigger. I tried reducing the value weightSum (of the top LinearLayout) from 3 to 2.5, turns out the the AHbottomNavigation is not visible anymore.

Comment: you mean you want to increase view pager size?

Comment: you can use RelativeLayout as your parent layout. Make your pager height wrap_content. and you RecyclerView - below the layout containing the pager and above AHbottomNavigation. that way the RecyclerView will occupy as much space as possible.

Comment: @VishalPatel no. take a look at the screenshot. the viewpager height itself is greater than the height of the images. i want it to be smaller.

Comment: ohk let me ans somthing for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  like below

### 1. Replace xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <!-- for displaying ads -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llDots"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />


    <!-- for displaying news -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/news_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
</LinearLayout>




<!-- bottom navigation -->
<com.aurelhubert.ahbottomnavigation.AHBottomNavigation
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

### 2.change view pager with wrap content

You can use the below code.

```
public class WrapContentViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private int mCurrentPagePosition = 0;

    public WrapContentViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public WrapContentViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        try {
            View child = getChildAt(mCurrentPagePosition);
            if (child != null) {
                child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
                heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    public void reMeasureCurrentPage(int position) {
        mCurrentPagePosition = position;
        requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Declare it in xml:

```
<your.package.name.WrapContentViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</your.package.name.WrapContentViewPager>
```

And call `reMeasureCurrentpage` function on page swipe.

```
final WrapContentViewPager wrapContentViewPager = (WrapContentViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

wrapContentViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                wrapContentViewPager.reMeasureCurrentPage(wrapContentViewPager.getCurrentItem());
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

happy coding :)

Comment: Hi Vishal. Looks kinda complicated, but hey it works. Anyway, I noticed on portrait orientation, the empty, vertical space occupied by the view pager is still a bit big. But on landscape orientation, it's obviously reduced. Maybe a should use bigger images?

Comment: can u attach your view pager Item xml file so i can help u